# Cookie is Not Set - Superagent

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, superagent

I am making a POST request on an API with superagent , this is basically a login api that signs a token and set cookie.

The code to make request from react  is as follows

```
     agent
        .post('http://localhost:3010/api/auth/login')
        .send({username:this.state.username,password:this.state.password})      
        .end((err,res)=>{
            if(err) console.log(err);
            if(res.body.auth===true){
                alert("Successful Login , You'll be Redirected");
                history.push('/dashboard');
            }
            });
```

In my express server I am using this code :

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, user) {

if (err) return res.status(500).send('Error on the server.');
if (!user) return res.status(404).send('No user found.');

var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
if (!passwordIsValid) return res.status(401).send({ auth: false, token: null });
var token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id, role : user.role }, config.secret, {
  expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
});
res.cookie('auth',token);
res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token });

  });
});
```

I am setting cookie in the response but the problem is the cookie is never set in the browser.
This issue is not when I am using POSTMAN to check APIS, but the problem emerges when consuming the apis in react in real browsers.

Where I am wrong ? Or what Else method should i use to acheive the result

Comment: have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are sending the token back to the client as part of the request accessible via the cookie attribute on the response object. Not storing the cookie in the browser cookie jar. To do that you'd need to look for the cookie as part of the superagent response callback and then save the cookie using localstorage client side.